# Windows Defender Trojan removal

Tags: trojan

Windows Defender Win10 removed a Trojan.  I clicked allow, by mistake, to allow the trojan through the firewall in the future. I cannot find the Trojan in the list of allowed apps when I check the firewall.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

Defender and Firewall are two separate things. Did you click to Defender ignore such thread, or you confirm thread asking for Firewall access rule creation? In second case, and if you do not remember thread filename, than you have to check all rules one by one, check related processes and disable rules its process is unknown to you.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I ran a Windows 10 Defender offline scan.  when I searched for the results there was a notification that a Trojan--- had been removed on 02/16 and the threat was severe.  There was a button below the report which said "Allow" and I thought it was to completely remove the trojan.  The report added that the trojan had been removed and that when I clicked Allow that I was allowing it to cross the Windows Firewall in any future access.  When I tried to return to report I could find no health reports or performance logs.  I obviously need to get this fixed immediately.  Thank you.

Comment: When I checked the Windows Firewall settings I could not find it in the list of allowed programs.

Comment: I have Malwarebytes installed but it did not report a trojan had been removed.

Comment: Did you try re-setting the two major components as I suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

Settings, Update and Security,   Firewall Settings. Use Restore Firewalls to Default. This will correct any settings you had made. Similarly (same general area) Virus and Threat protection. Click on Allowed Threats and see if the Trojan is there. Remove it if so.

These two things: Restore Firewall to Defaults and Removing Allowed Threats should re-secure your system.

Comment: Yes, I did restore the Firewalls to default. The Trojan had been removed.  The health report that told me about the trojan and the path it took and the screenshots I took have "disappeared"  I cannot find them anywhere.